# Can Getting Fuel Injectors or Ignition Coils Wet Ruin Them?

Tags: suzuki, misfire, ignition-coil, fuel-injectors

I have a 2005 Suzuki Forenza Wagon where I recently cleaned the engine compartment. I was a little careless during the cleaning and water got in under the spark plug wires to sit around the top of the spark plugs in the head. As can be imagined this caused a terrible misfire problem for the car.

I proceeded to remove the water, replace the plugs, and replace the plug wires after this. The misfire improved and the engine runs okay most of the time. However, I still experience a severe bogging down of the engine once in awhile while accelerating (especially onto the interstate or up hills) where the car refuses to accelerate until it seems to kick itself and the rpms jump up before the car accelerates.

My question is: could getting the fuel injectors and/or coil pack wet have ruined them and would this cause the intermittent acceleration issues? I have used fuel injector cleaner a couple of times through the gas tank in an effort to remove residual water. This seems to mildly help at best. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure about your spark plugs, it surely is a coil pack. 100%.

---

If your spark plug does not give a spark, but the coil is good, and you don't replace the plug, it will ruin the coil. And even when you replace spark plug, it still will misfire, as you say, on acceleration until certain RPMs.